# Is there any way to make parameterization dynamic in Python/Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I am currently working on tests for a railway logistics system. The tests involve passing several JSONs as parameters to the tests. However, each JSON file corresponds to a different test case, such as releasing trains with loaded or empty wagons or checking the consistency of wagon supply in a station. My problem is that I am currently passing all JSONs to all tests, which causes unnecessary complications. I need to create validations to skip tests that are irrelevant to certain JSON files.

As an example, I have included the code for one of the tests below:

```py
NODES_LIST = ['ECA', 'ECE', 'EDV', 'EYU', 'VEB', 'VIC', 'VOB', 'VTU']
SKIP_JSON = 'The test case file is not for the offer empty test.'
SKIP_NODE = 'The test case file is for the offer empty test, but does not apply to this station.' day of the current shift and the previous shift are not the same.'

@pytest.mark.parametrize('node_name', NODES_LIST)
def test_offer_empty_consistency(input_json_filename: str, node_name: str):
    if ('offer_empty' not in input_json_filename):
        pytest.skip(SKIP_JSON)
    elif (((node_name in ['ECA', 'ECE', 'EDV', 'EYU', 'VEB', 'VOB']) and ('generic' not in input_json_filename)) or ((node_name in ['VIC', 'VTU']) and (node_name not in input_json_filename))):
        pytest.skip(SKIP_NODE)

    expected_offer_empty, really_offer_empty = offer_empty_consistency(input_json_filename=input_json_filename, node_name=node_name)

    assert expected_offer_empty == really_offer_empty, f'Failure.\nExpected empty offer values [{expected_offer_empty}] differ from actual values [{really_offer_empty}] for station {node_name}.'
```

In this example above, which is how I'm currently doing it, imagining that I pass 3 json files `['CT_01_offer_empty_generic', 'CT_02_offer_empty_VIC', 'CT_03_offer_empty_VTU']`, this would generate the following test configuration:

```
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-ECA]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-ECE]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-EDV]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-EYU]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-VEB]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-VIC]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-VOB]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-VTU]

test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_02_offer_empty_VIC-ECA]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_02_offer_empty_VIC-ECE]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_02_offer_empty_VIC-EDV]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_02_offer_empty_VIC-EYU]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_02_offer_empty_VIC-VEB]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_02_offer_empty_VIC-VIC]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_02_offer_empty_VIC-VOB]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_02_offer_empty_VIC-VTU]

test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_03_offer_empty_VTU-ECA]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_03_offer_empty_VTU-ECE]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_03_offer_empty_VTU-EDV]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_03_offer_empty_VTU-EYU]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_03_offer_empty_VTU-VEB]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_03_offer_empty_VTU-VIC]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_03_offer_empty_VTU-VOB]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_03_offer_empty_VTU-VTU]
```

what is "wrong", because it is creating many settings that will be skipped, what I really want is something more optimized and dynamic, the expected result is:

```
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-ECA]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-ECE]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-EDV]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-EYU]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-VEB]
test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_01_offer_empty_generic-VOB]

test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_02_offer_empty_VIC-VIC]

test_offer_empty_consistency[CT_03_offer_empty_VTU-VTU]
```

My attempt to make the tests more dynamic involved creating a class that would receive the correct JSONs via parameterization and then would utilize the `__init__` method to pass necessary information to the test methods. However, as seen in the parameterization of `node_name`, the `self` variable was not accessible.

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('input_json_filename', test_related_lists.OFFER_EMPTY)
class TestOfferEmpty:
    def __init__(self, input_json_filename) -> None:
        self.test_data = get_test_data(input_json_filename=input_json_filename)
        if 'generic' in input_json_filename:
            self.nodes = ['ECA', 'ECE', 'EDV', 'EYU', 'VEB', 'VOB']
        elif 'VIC' in input_json_filename:
            self.nodes = ['VIC']
        else:
            self.nodes = ['VTU']

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('node_name', self.nodes)
    def test_offer_empty_consistency(self, node_name: str):
        expected_offer_empty, really_offer_empty = offer_empty_consistency(test_data=self.test_data, node_name=node_name)

        assert expected_offer_empty == really_offer_empty, f'Failure.\nExpected empty offer values [{expected_offer_empty}] differ from actual values [{really_offer_empty}] for station {node_name}.'
```

Is there a way to pass only the relevant JSONs to their corresponding tests, without having to perform several validations and skips? Currently, the JSONs are passed through parameterization in a conftest.py file.

```py
from science_vli_qa.tests.utils import get_input_files_list


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--input_json_filename", action="store", default=None)


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if option_value := metafunc.config.option.input_json_filename:
        params = option_value.split(",")
        input_names = []
        for ct in params:
            formatted_ct_name = ct if ct.endswith('.json') else f'{ct}.json'
            input_names.append(formatted_ct_name)
        if 'input_json_filename' in metafunc.fixturenames:
            metafunc.parametrize("input_json_filename", input_names)
    elif 'input_json_filename' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("input_json_filename", get_input_files_list())
```

Comment: See https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/how-to/parametrize.html#pytest-generate-tests

Comment: @AKX This way I have to pass the names of the jsons through the command line, which is not feasible, since there are more than 50 jsons and it only increases every day. I already have a conftest.py file with this option, but I don't use it precisely because it's not feasible, instead I use that "test_related_lists" module that I'm using in the parameterization of the class, and through it I can get the lists with the names of jsons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to split test inputs/outputs between two parameterization lists (i.e. one that goes to the `input_json_filename` fixture, and another that goes directly to the test).  My experience is that  there's no good way to do this, and the need to do it is probably a sign that your tests should be refactored a bit.

The problem is that you can't know what the output of a test is supposed to be unless you also know all the inputs.  So if the inputs and outputs are split between multiple parametrization lists, you have to be careful how you combine those lists, because not every combination will be valid.  As far as I know, pytest always tests every combination of every parameter provided for every test case, so it's just not meant to be used like this.

As a brief aside, the way pytest behaves makes sense when you think about parameters that have no effect on the inputs or outputs of a test.  For example, maybe you want to test against multiple database backends, but you expect the same results with each one.  A parametrized database fixture would be perfect for this.

With that in mind, here are some changes you might think about making to your tests.  I acknowledge that I don't understand the whole context of your tests, so some of these suggestions might not be practical, but hopefully the ideas at least make sense:

- Get rid of the `input_json_filename` fixture.  Fixtures are meant for efficiently setting up and tearing down test environments.  When they are parametrized, it should only be with the kinds of parameters that don't affect test results, as in the database example above.  Based on what you've shown here, it doesn't seem like `input_json_filename` really needs to be a fixture.

  The alternative would be just to load all the JSON files into some global variable.  You could then construct parametrization lists from this variable:

  ```py
  JSON_FILES = {'path1.json': {...}, 'path2.json': {...}}

  @pytest.mark.parametrize('path, node', [
      ('path1.json', 'ECA'),
      ('path1.json', 'ECE'),
      ('path2.json', 'VIC'),
  ])
  def test_offer_empty_consistency(path, node):
      json_contents = JSON_FILES[path]
      ...
  ```

  You could also calculate the test cases algorithmically:

  ```py
  def iter_test_cases():
      for path in JSON_FILES:
          if 'generic' in path:
              for node in ['ECA', 'ECE', 'EDV', 'EYU', 'VEB', 'VOB']:
                  yield path, node
          elif 'VIC' in input_json_filename:
              yield path, 'VIC'
          else:
              yield path, 'VTU'

  @pytest.mark.parametrize('path, node', iter_test_cases())
  def test_offer_empty_consistency(path, node):
      ...
  ```
- Don't parametrize the `input_json_filename` fixture.

  A less-extreme version of the above recommendation is to keep `input_json_filename` as a fixture, but to have it be a single object that just provides access to every available JSON file.  You could then treat it much like the global variable in the above snippets.
- Get rid of the `--input_json_filename` argument.  Especially since the test apparently requires specific combinations of JSON files and node names, it doesn't make sense to let the user supply never-before-seen JSON files at run time (without also specifying a node name).  Having this argument also doesn't give you any extra control over which tests are run, because you can already use the `-k` option select tests with certain parameter values.  Likely there's some missing context here, but I'm generally *very* skeptical of using command-line arguments to supply test data.  I also suspect that getting rid of this argument would make it easier to implement the other suggestions I made.

Again, I know this turned into more of a code review than an answer to your question, but I hope some of these suggestions are useful.

---

I wrote a package called [Parametrize From File](https://parametrize-from-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that's meant to make it easier to load test parameters from data files.  I'm not sure if it would be helpful in your case, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: The second suggestion worked perfectly, really parameterizing the jsons was a problem, and the command line option I had imported from another project with similar tests, but here it ended up never being used, so I finally got rid of it.

Comment: This suggestion will greatly reduce the execution time of all the tests, every day new jsons are inserted in the repository, which was greatly increasing the execution time of the tests, it was already reaching 1hr of execution, but a good part of this execution time was due to these creations of useless test cases between the combinations of jsons and nodes names, which ended up being skipped, but with this implementation it is now possible to make these combinations in the most optimized as possible, without creating any unnecessary combinations and without having to skip any tests

Comment: That's great to hear, glad I could help!

Comment: @MadSweeney  Didn't you notice how much of this answer was written by ChatGPT?